# I need to pass along with the dollar amount AND the Confirmation # for a transaction to ET Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, xml, history-tracking, conversion, transaction

Is it possible to attach a confirmation number from My Website once a person transacts to ExactTarget tracking so that I'm also able to see it in the feed that comes through with the dollar amounts? If so, what tag within the Script does it have to go under?

Here's the code provided to my by ET.

```
<system>
    <system_name>tracking</system_name> 
    <action>conversion</action>
    <member_id>20496</member_id> 
    <job_id>162951</job_id> 
    <email>help@example.com</email> 
    <list>84560_HTML</list> 
    <original_link_id>3531372</original_link_id> 
    <BatchID>36</BatchID> 
    <conversion_link_id>1</conversion_link_id> 
    <link_alias>Tennis Ball Product Display Page</link_alias> 
    <display_order>3</display_order> 
    <data_set><data amt="100" unit="Dollars" accumulate="true"/>
</data_set> 
</system>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many fields as you want within the  node.
For example you can use something like this:

```
<data_set>
<data amt="6.55" unit="Dollars" accumulate="true"/>
<data amt="1.0" unit="Number of Roses" accumulate="true"/>
<data amt="1.0" unit="Number of Lilacs" accumulate="true"/>
</data_set>
```

There are more examples here:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/conversion_tracking/